# Java regular expression on matching asterisk only when it is the last character

Tags: java, regex

Anyone can spot any error in this code?

```
    String value = "/files/etc/hosts/*";
    if (value.matches("\\*$")) {
        System.out.println("MATCHES!");
    }
```

I am trying to do some operation when the last character of a string is an asterisk.

The syntax looks correct to me, I tested it on http://regexpal.com/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is the `n`th post, with `n` very high, by someone yet again victim of `.matches()` being a misnomer :p You are not the first, and you won't be the last...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why not just use:

```
if (value.endsWith("*")) {
```

Comment: duh, didn't thought of using that.  Thanks

Comment: It seems so easy when you look at someone elses code. It's so hard when you have to look at your own code and see the simple stuff.

Answer (score 6):

String.matches() only returns true if the regex matches the entire CharSequence.

Try either this:

```
value.matches(".*?\\*$")
```

Or use a Pattern object.

EDIT: Per comment request.

```
Pattern glob = Pattern.compile("\\*$");
if (glob.matcher(value).find()) {
    System.out.println("MATCHES!");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to match everything in the `String` when using `String#matches`:

```
if (value.matches(".*\\*$")) {
```

Comment: Why match the _whole_ input when what is required to match is only the star and end of input?